# Sync mismatches - CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: agile, continuous-integration, integration-tests, devops

We are implementing CI/CD in our company and we have a regulatory project which takes a long time to test. There is no way to break it down since the project contains around 300 rules, each of which needs to be tested every time. Other projects have a much smaller time of testing and they checkin with the mainline much more frequently. For the regulatory project, we pull from the mainline and do an integration test, but by the time we check in, there are 10s of checkins from other projects and these would again have to be tested. Any and all help would be appreciated!

In the diagram attached, the Project B indicates the regulatory project and during the testing period of Project B, Project A has checked in twice and synced with the mainline.

[image: Sample Pipeline]

Comment: You cannot have your cake and eat it too. Fast, automated testing is critical for good CD pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Optimising your testing is probably the first thing you should look at.  That said it will likely not be enough.  Few strategies you can look into, each with their own set of drawbacks so it will inevitably be a compromise.

**Isolate the projects release**
Separate both projects in their own repo/build pipeline and integrate them as external dependencies.  This way their commit cycles will not interfere with one another.  Treat Project A as it's own product/library and release it with it's own versioning scheme.  Project B is then free to integrate the version of it's choosing and test with that.
Drawback with this approach is that Project B is always lagging behind project A's development.  Should another project depend on both A and B it will be lagging behind B and get it's dependencies from B.  This means that any changes made to A will have to trickle down at a much slower pace to the final product because it will have to create a release, wait for B to make this release at a dependencies and then wait for B to finish testing and make a release of it's own.
Note this does not mean slower development, just that changes made from A will take longer time to reach the final product.  That said, it will make it much more predictable.

**Freeze main branch during B's testing until it is integrated**
A's development will continue in it's own branch but will not be able to merge into the main until B's testing is finished and has merged itself into the main.

It you only have these two projects then it's not so bad.  Should you have others that have a similar commit frequency as A then they should all be on the same branch (say a main branch where B gets it's stuff and is committed to, a dev branch where everything else go to and from and itself goes to and from the main branch.

Again, here you are slowing down to the pace of the slowest.  Key here is to not halt everything altogether so A's dev can continue but will only sync at specific times with main.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that a different source control workflow may help. [This page by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) offers a good comparison of different flows.

In particular, git-flow could help resolve this problem. The concept is similar to what @Newtopian described. If you had a separate branch for regulatory testing between your `develop` and `master` branches, developers could check in frequently into develop, and periodic (overnight?) merges, builds, and tests could be run from the regulatory-testing branch. Git-flow talks about 'rules of the road' to minimizes integration issues.